# Example needed: Xcode 6 iOs draw lines between two labels

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, label

Ive only recently gotten into `Xcode` and have struck a wall with drawing basic black lines that would connect two labels.

I would really appreciate a simple example of how I could do the following:

1. Get the location of any label N and N1
2. Draw a line between these labels

Comment: You get the location of the label from its frame. You can draw a line using a UIBezierPath. You should look into these, and make an attempt at solving this yourself. If you can't get it to work, come back with a specific question based on the code you tried.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you for the tips. I'm looking at code like the one below, but cant get far with it. Ill edit my question later as I progress and hopefully have something that is more interesting to look at.
UIBezierPath * path;
    [path moveToPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 500)] // X and Y, start point
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPoint(x: 100, y: 550)] // X2 and Y2, end point